# Make a cell in google sheets automatically 'insert comment'

Tags: google-sheets, insert

I don't think I explained it well, column L is where I can log what I have done - with a date and time, so say I send a message, I would log MESSAGE SENT then say I make a call I could log CALLED and any info I wanted to remember - each entry being date and time stamped

[image]

In the image you can see the comment field - all i want is that to pop up when I click on the cell and be able to add to the comment field

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onSelectionChange(e) trigger and check if the selected cell(s) fall into your criteria, if so then insert comment.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Answer (score 0):

You could use this sample script to set a comment on an edited cell:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}
```

However this requires that you edit the content of the cell to trigger the `onEdit()` function. Which you can modify instead to trigger the function manually (or assign the script to an image to act as a button) like so.

```
function setComment() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getRange('L14:L16').setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date()); 
}
```

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNote(String)
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite